# Is there any way to preinstall an apache server in Eclipse (on first startup)

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

i've done a lot of research but i couldn't find any useful links or topics.

So here is my problem: I've been trying to include/preinstall an apache tomcat server in my eclipse environment (see Screenshot). I want to do this without user-interaction.
But i can't find any related topics. Just a lot how to include tomcat in eclipse(while it is open).

[Screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/854/mowr.png/)

Is there a file where i have to add settings? Is it even possible to do this?

Eclipse Kepler 4.3 is running on this machine(Win 7 Prof 64x) and Apache Tomcat 7.0.42. Both are already installed.

I want to deploy an Installer for this.